# How to import a Angular Component with own module?

Tags: angular, components, angular9

**EDIT:**

:facepalm: Found the error...

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
   <app-contact-element [contact]="contact"></app-contact-element>
</div>

contacts.length == 0
```

---

I want to import a custom component (contact.component) with own module into my other component (event-info.component). I don't know how to configure the modules...

Here is my solution so far. There are no errors, but the component is not visible. I also added address.component (without module) to event-info. This works.

- event

  - event.module

    - **event-info.component**
    - event-other.component
- contact

  - contact.module
  - **contact.component**
- address

  - address.component

---

event.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ContactModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    EventInfoComponent,
    AddressComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class EventModule {}
```

event-info.component.html

```
<app-contact-element [contact]="contact"></app-contact-element>
<app-address-element [address]="address"></app-address-element>
```

---

contact.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AvatarModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ContactComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ContactComponent
  ]
})
export class ContactModule {}
```

contact and address.component are very simple and have only a text in html and an `@Input() contact;` with ngOnInit log of input value in component.

There is a log output from address but not from contact

Comment: Where do you use `EventInfoComponent`? There are no `exports` components in `EventModule` so I don't think it is used anywhere

Comment: is the text of ContactComponent being displayed?

Comment: @GérômeGrignon no

Comment: @RazRonen there is also an event.component, controlling some other via ComponentFactoryResolver.  This is a shortened version of my code to fokus on the problem

Comment: :facepalm: *ngFor over array with length of 0 - The problem is always the user

Comment: I made a mistake elsewhere. There can be no correct answer